# SQL Server case input_expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

The syntax for the simple `CASE` expression is on the Microsoft documentation as follows;

```
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Is it possible to do the following without rewriting the query for the `input_expression` the second time?

```
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE **input_expression** ] 
END
```

Thanks!

Eds

Comment: yes. `Case a when 1 then 2 else a end` will work

Comment: You can use a Boolean variable to store the result of input_expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** `input_expression` can't be `NULL`, **and** there's only one `WHEN` branch, then you could write:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(input_expression,when_expression),result_expression)
```

Otherwise, if the complexity of `input_expression` is too much, consider moving it's computation inside of a subquery. So, instead of:

```
SELECT
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     ELSE input_expression 
END,
--Other columns
FROM
   --Rest of query
```

You would have:

```
SELECT
CASE ie
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     ELSE ie
END,
--Other columns
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      input_expression as ie,
      --Other columns
   FROM
      --Rest of query
   ) t
```

Comment: Its not perfect, but I think the subquiery will work fine. Thanks for your help, Damien.